# EXCEL VBA : Dynamic Lookup - Two columns, enter data in either and return value for the other

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a "lookup" spreadsheet whereby I would have two columns (let's say, Prod_Format_A and Prod_Format_B). These would be two versions of a product identifier. I would like the user to be able to enter either format A or format B and have the other one returned...

So if I enter a format A code, I should get back a format B code. 
If I enter a format B code, I should get back a format A code.

What's the easiest way to go about this? Obviously I would have a separate lookup table to resolve against.

Thank you.

Comment: This would be easily resolved through smart use of excel formulas. Something like `=IfError(IfError(Vlookup(Value, Table1, Column, False), Vlookup(Value, Table1, Column, False)), "-")` Something like this would check `Table1` for the item, if not found it would check `Table2` if it isnt found there then it returns "-" (which is just intended to replace the `#N/A`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brandon. This can be solved with smart use of formula. But, I would like to suggest Index Match combination. Since, the table contains 2 columns only and vlookup will only get the left most column as the look up.

=IFERROR(INDEX(PROD_FORMATA, MATCH(, PROD_FOMRATB, )),INDEX(PROD_FORMATB, MATCH(, PROD_FOMRATA, )))

Match will return a number depending on the location of the table
Index on the other hand will return the value in the range given the number.

```
| A          | B       |
| ---------- | ------- |
| Ball       | Sports  |
| Pen        | Writing |
| Cookie     | Food    |
| Pencil     | Writing |
| Test       | Object  |
```

=MATCH("TEST",A1:A5,0)
returns 5

=INDEX(B1:B5,5)
returns "Object"

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the code of the sheet (not a module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(Target.Address), Sheet1.Range("E1:F20"), 2, False)
    Else
    End If

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(Target.Address), Sheet1.Range("F1:G20"), 2, False)
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

you ll need to have your 2 vlookup tables E1:F20 and F1:G20 (columns E and G are the same, but we need G because vlookup looks at the leftmost column of our data)